# Team Foundation Server SDK samples

Tags: tfs, sdk

Can anybody point me to the C# samples for the TFS SDK please?

I have looked high and low and cannot seem to find the samples or the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [this official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Additional%20Resources) which have some examples and all namespaces.

Below example shows how to programmatically connect to a server that is running Team Foundation and then access the team projects, list project info.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client; 
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;

namespace TfsApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            // Connect to Team Foundation Server
            //     Server is the name of the server that is running the application tier for Team Foundation.
            //     Port is the port that Team Foundation uses. The default port is 8080.
            //     VDir is the virtual path to the Team Foundation application. The default path is tfs.
            Uri tfsUri = (args.Length < 1) ? 
                new Uri("http://Server:Port/VDir") : new Uri(args[0]);

            TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer =
                TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(tfsUri);

            // Get the catalog of team project collections
            ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> collectionNodes = configurationServer.CatalogNode.QueryChildren(
                new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection },
                false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);

            // List the team project collections
            foreach (CatalogNode collectionNode in collectionNodes)
            {
                // Use the InstanceId property to get the team project collection
                Guid collectionId = new Guid(collectionNode.Resource.Properties["InstanceId"]);
                TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = configurationServer.GetTeamProjectCollection(collectionId);

                // Print the name of the team project collection
                Console.WriteLine("Collection: " + teamProjectCollection.Name);

                // Get a catalog of team projects for the collection
                ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> projectNodes = collectionNode.QueryChildren(
                    new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.TeamProject },
                    false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);

                // List the team projects in the collection
                foreach (CatalogNode projectNode in projectNodes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Team Project: " + projectNode.Resource.DisplayName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some wonderful blogs including multiple API samples for your reference:

- [TFS API-Buck Hodges](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/tag/TFS-API/)
- [TFS API Index- Shai Raiten's Blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2011/05/18/tfs-api-index-parts-1-to-37/) (Even though the sample is C++, still very helpful)